# Intercept the Shipment

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You are to capture one of the biggest shipment of illegal drugs. The only problem is that your team just narrowed it down to 4 locations:

**Minnesota**

**Florida**

**Virginia**

**California**

You don't have enough men to cover the port of four cities and you can only cover one. The only information that you can rely on that can help you decide on which city is the text message you had intercepted last week.

Text message:

*Shipment next week, coordinates 64,14,85,84,72,58,41. Don't messed up, Don Antonio San Carlos II will be there, Hernando Exum and Octavio are not. The wolves might be there, be careful.*

Can you get to the right city before the shipment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is

> Florida.

because

> Antonio San Carlos II -> ASCII
>  Hernando Exum and Octavio are not -> decimal, not hex or octal.
>  This translates to @SOUTH:)
>  So I think Florida because it's the southernmost of the states.

Comment: that was fast :)